# Are overlapping sub-arrays of a byte array independent enough to use as hash function(s) for Bloom Filter?

Tags: statistics, correlation, bloom-filter

I have the following question in the context of a BloomFilter.  BloomFilters need to have `k` independent hash functions.  Let's call these function `h1, h2, ... hk`.  Independent in this context means that their value will have very little correlation (hopefully zero) when applied to the same set.  See the Algorithm Description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter (but of course, you already know that page inside out :).

Now, assume that I want to define my hash functions using some `n` bits (coming from a crypto function if you must know, but it's not relevant for the question), which are independent from each other themselves.  If you want more context you can read http://bitworking.org/news/380/bloom-filter-resources which is doing something similar.

For example, assume I want to define each `h` as (pardon my pseudo-code):

```
bytes = MD5(value)
h1 = bytes[0-3] as Integer
h2 = bytes[4-7] as Integer
h3 = bytes[8-11] as Integer
...
```

Of course we will run out of hash functions very quickly.  We only get four in this MD5 example.

One possibility is to let the hash functions overlap with each other and not have the requirement that the four bytes are sequential.  That way we has many hash functions as permutations the byte array allows.  To keep it simple, what if we defined the hash functions in the following way:

```
bytes = MD5(value)
h1 = bytes[0-3] as Integer
h2 = bytes[1-4] as Integer
h3 = bytes[2-5] as Integer
...
```

It is easy to see that in the MD5 case now we have 12 hashing functions instead of four.

Finally, we get to **THE** question.  Are these hashing functions independent?  Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I decided to try to answer the question from a practical point of view so I created a small program that would test the hypothesis.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case with clever questions, the answer is yes, and no.

Yes, in the sense that there are 16 bits that are not shared between h1 and h2.  No, in the senses that are important to you (unless you are only actually using eight bits of the hash function, which I presume you are not).

The issue here is less with dependence between the two functions applied to the same item being inserted and more (in this case, in my opinion) with the functions being applied to multiple items.

Think of it this way.  Assume your first example uses g1-g4, and the second uses h1-h4.  Two items whose MD5sum (or any other hashing function) overlaps in only 5 consecutive bytes (unlikely, but statistically do-able, especially if you're trying) will stand a chance of colliding if just using h1 and h2, h2 and h3, or h3 and h4.  Meanwhile g1-g4 is robust to that possibility.

Now collisions with bloom filters aren't as big a deal as other applications of hash functions, but you should keep in mind that the overlapping bytes do detract from the utility of the hash functions.  I'm a little surprised that you need more than four indepdendent hash functions, to be honest.

Also, if you're only using the last 8 bits of each number (256 bit bloom filter) or the last 16 bits (2^16 bit bloom filter), or whatever, then you can 'overlap' the bits that you aren't using with reckless abandon and without risk.

Disclaimer:
I know cryptography pretty well and bloom filters because they are fricking awesome, but my practical knowledge of bloom filters is limited; what you describe may work quite well for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think I understand the tradeoffs you are describing.  However, I am not sure I understand your point about hash collisions.  In the example I gave the bytes were coming from MD5, but they could just as well come from Java's [Random.nextBytes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes(byte[])) function.  In this case the question would be: when we generate a sequence byte arrays `b1, b2, b3 ...` and interpret a subchain as an integer (for example `b2[3-7]`), will the two subchains have a high or low correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Running the program below will test the hypothesis with random number generators.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int R = 100, N = 10000, W = 8;
    double[] totals = new double[33];
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int k = 0; k < R; k++) {
        // Generate 10,000 random byte arrays
        byte[][] bytes = new byte[N][W];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) r.nextBytes(bytes[i]);

        double[] a1 = new double[N], a2 = new double[N];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {

            // Extract arrays
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                a1[j] = readInt(bytes[j], 0, 31);
                a2[j] = readInt(bytes[j], 32 - i, 31);
            }

            double c = (new PearsonsCorrelation()).correlation(a1, a2);
            totals[i] += c;
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting bits is that only when there is only one overlapping bit, the correlation starts to be significant.  Below are the pearson correlation coefficients for each number of overlapping bits.  We start very low (meaning close to the `0` overlapping case), and get `1` when they fully overlap.

```
0   -0.001883705757299319
1   -0.0019261826793995395
2   -0.0018466135577488883
3   -0.001499114477250019
4   -0.0010874727770462341
5   -1.1219111699336884E-5
6   -0.001760700583842139
7   3.6545455908216937E-4
8   0.0014823972050436482
9   0.0014809963180788554
10  0.0015226692114697182
11  0.00199027499920776
12  0.001720451344380218
13  -2.0219121772336676E-4
14  6.880004078769847E-4
15  8.605949344202965E-4
16  -0.0025640320027890645
17  -0.002552269654230886
18  -0.002550425130285998
19  -0.002522446787072504
20  -0.00320337678141518
21  -7.554573868921899E-4
22  -6.463448718890875E-4
23  -3.4709181348336335E-4
24  0.0038077518094915912
25  0.0037865326140343815
26  0.0038728464390708982
27  0.0035091958914765407
28  0.005099109955591643
29  0.016993434043779915
30  0.06120260114179265
31  0.25159073855202346
32  1.0
```

**Bottom line**: It seems that a shift of one byte (meaning the 24 value above) should be quite safe with respect to hash function generation.